# How to make Event Calendar Widget work locally?

Tags: html

I have been looking for a local running calendar widget I can open and use in a browser tab and I came across this page:

```js
!function() {

  var today = moment();

  function Calendar(selector, events) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.events = events;
    this.current = moment().date(1);
    this.draw();
    var current = document.querySelector('.today');
    if(current) {
      var self = this;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.openDay(current);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
    //Create Header
    this.drawHeader();

    //Draw Month
    this.drawMonth();

    this.drawLegend();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
    var self = this;
    if(!this.header) {
      //Create the header elements
      this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
      this.header.className = 'header';

      this.title = createElement('h1');

      var right = createElement('div', 'right');
      right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });

      var left = createElement('div', 'left');
      left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });

      //Append the Elements
      this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
      this.header.appendChild(right);
      this.header.appendChild(left);
      this.el.appendChild(this.header);
    }

    this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     ev.date = self.current.clone().date(Math.random() * (29 - 1) + 1);
    });
    
    
    if(this.month) {
      this.oldMonth = this.month;
      this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
      this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
        self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        self.backFill();
        self.currentMonth();
        self.fowardFill();
        self.el.appendChild(self.month);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
        }, 16);
      });
    } else {
        this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        this.el.appendChild(this.month);
        this.backFill();
        this.currentMonth();
        this.fowardFill();
        this.month.className = 'month new';
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }

    clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();

    while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
      this.drawDay(clone);
      clone.add('days', 1);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
    if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
      this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
      this.month.appendChild(this.week);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
    var self = this;
    this.getWeek(day);

    //Outer Day
    var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
    outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.openDay(this);
    });

    //Day Name
    var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));

    //Day Number
    var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));


    //Events
    var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
    this.drawEvents(day, events);

    outer.appendChild(name);
    outer.appendChild(number);
    outer.appendChild(events);
    this.week.appendChild(outer);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
    if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
      var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
        if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
          memo.push(ev);
        }
        return memo;
      }, []);

      todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
        var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
        element.appendChild(evSpan);
      });
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
    classes = ['day'];
    if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
      classes.push('other');
    } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
      classes.push('today');
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

    var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');

    //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
    if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
      details = currentOpened;
      arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
    } else {
      //Close the open events on differnt week row
      //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      if(currentOpened) {
        currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.className = 'details out';
      }

      //Create the Details Container
      details = createElement('div', 'details in');

      //Create the arrow
      var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');

      //Create the event wrapper

      details.appendChild(arrow);
      el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
    }

    var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
      if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
        memo.push(ev);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);

    this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);

    arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
  }

  Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
    //Remove any events in the current details element
    var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
    var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));

    events.forEach(function(ev) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event');
      var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
      var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);

      div.appendChild(square);
      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    });

    if(!events.length) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
      var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Events');

      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    }

    if(currentWrapper) {
      currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
    } else {
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawLegend = function() {
    var legend = createElement('div', 'legend');
    var calendars = this.events.map(function(e) {
      return e.calendar + '|' + e.color;
    }).reduce(function(memo, e) {
      if(memo.indexOf(e) === -1) {
        memo.push(e);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []).forEach(function(e) {
      var parts = e.split('|');
      var entry = createElement('span', 'entry ' +  parts[1], parts[0]);
      legend.appendChild(entry);
    });
    this.el.appendChild(legend);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    this.current.add('months', 1);
    this.next = true;
    this.draw();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
    this.current.subtract('months', 1);
    this.next = false;
    this.draw();
  }

  window.Calendar = Calendar;

  function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
    var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
    if(className) {
      ele.className = className;
    }
    if(innerText) {
      ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
    }
    return ele;
  }
}();

!function() {
  var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Interview - Jr. Web Developer', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Demo New App to the Board', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },
    { eventName: 'Dinner w/ Marketing', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange' },

    { eventName: 'Game vs Portalnd', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Houston', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs Denver', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },
    { eventName: 'Game vs San Degio', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue' },

    { eventName: 'School Play', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Parent/Teacher Conference', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Pick up from Soccer Practice', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },
    { eventName: 'Ice Cream Night', calendar: 'Kids', color: 'yellow' },

    { eventName: 'Free Tamale Night', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Bowling Team', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Teach Kids to Code', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' },
    { eventName: 'Startup Weekend', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green' }
  ];

  

  function addDate(ev) {
    
  }

  var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);

}();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue UltraLight', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #4A4A4A;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

#calendar {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 570px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 420px;
  background: rgba(66, 66, 66, 1);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  border-width: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(160, 159, 160, 1) transparent transparent;
  left: 20px;
}

.right {
  border-width: 7.5px 0 7.5px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(160, 159, 160, 1);
  right: 20px;
}

.month {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.month.new {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.next {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  animation: moveFromTopFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.next {
  -webkit-animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  animation: moveToTopFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.in.prev {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  animation: moveFromBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.month.out.prev {
  -webkit-animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  -moz-animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  animation: moveToBottomFadeMonth .4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.week {
 background: #4A4A4A;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.day.other {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.day.today {
  color: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1);
}

.day-name {
  font-size: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}

.day-number {
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}


.day .day-events {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 12px;
  line-height: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day .day-events span {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  line-height: 5px;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.blue { background: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1); }
.orange { background: rgba(247, 167, 0, 1); }
.green { background: rgba(153, 198, 109, 1); }
.yellow { background: rgba(249, 233, 0, 1); }

.details {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  height: 75px;
  background: rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.details.in {
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
  animation: moveFromTopFade .5s ease both;
}

.details.out {
  -webkit-animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
  -moz-animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
  animation: moveToTopFade .5s ease both;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(164, 164, 164, 1) transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.events {
  height: 75px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.events.in {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
  animation: fadeIn .3s ease both;
}

.events.in {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

.details.out .events {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutShrink .4s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutShink .4s ease both;
  animation: fadeOutShink .4s ease both;
}

.events.out {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
  animation: fadeOut .3s ease both;
}

.event {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.event.empty {
  color: #eee;
}

.event-category {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.event span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}

.legend {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(60, 60, 60, 1);
  line-height: 30px;

}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
}

.entry:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 12px;
  left: 14px;
}

.entry.blue:after { background: rgba(156, 202, 235, 1); }
.entry.orange:after { background: rgba(247, 167, 0, 1); }
.entry.green:after { background: rgba(153, 198, 109, 1); }
.entry.yellow:after { background: rgba(249, 233, 0, 1); }

/* Animations are cool!  */
@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { opacity: .3; height:0px; margin-top:0px; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { height:0px; margin-top:0px; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromTopFade {
  from { height:0px; margin-top:0px; transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { opacity: .3; height:0px; margin-top:0px; opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { height:0px; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes moveToTopFade {
  to { height:0px; transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}
@keyframes moveToTopFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(30%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromTopFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%); }
}
@keyframes moveToBottomFadeMonth {
  to { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%) scale(.95); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}
@keyframes moveFromBottomFadeMonth {
  from { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn  {
  from { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut  {
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
@keyframes fadeOutShink  {
  to { opacity: 0; padding: 0px; height: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In order to use it I did clone it so I can download it (strange that you cannot download it directly). Then I unzipped the file and opened one of the `.html` files in a browser. But the browser tab just is blank.

So how can I use this calendar locally? Or is this something else? The `README.md` is also practically empty....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look into index.html file, you'll see it does not include bundled script.js and style.css files. So you need to include those:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Also, it can't include moment.min.js file. `//` in the src means it should use the same protocol you access your index.html file with. On Codepen, that would be `https://`. But when you open the file locally, protocol becomes `file://` and your browser tries to open local file `cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js`, which obviously isn't there.

Since you want this to work offline, you need to download it and save it into same folder where you script is. So go here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js and save it to the same folder with your index.html file. Then change

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="moment.min.js"></script>`.

Your resulting index.html file should look like this:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that seems to work! But why is it to badly documented? Are they expecting perfect expert to use their examples? On the contrast, you give a clear and understandable explanation of what needs to be done and *why* it needs to be done! Thank you